.net 8 cache policy: return from cache when web API/action fails for some reason
I have to work in a project with data sources of all kinds, from SOAP, Rest, FTP, XLS, and what not. I make these different data sources availabe through a separate web API application in .net 8, which serves a common endpoint for all data.
However, these data sources are really unreliable and tend to fail rather often, for many reasons. Mainly because the suppliers have terrible IT systems.
Is there a simple way to return the last HTTP cache entry as the result for the query, when some internal error occurs?
I am currently caching for a certain time already, the question if I can make some kind of cache policy which updates the cache when the controller action is executed succesfully (and keeps that entry for a timespan x) and if that controller action raises any error, the last cache key is just retuned.
